# Spotify API-NET: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, spotify

[Using Spotify-API-NET library](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET)
I am trying to connect to my spotify client however I always get this message:

> Unable to connect to the remote server.

I seen other topics, that are written about same issues, with other API's so this must be problem with c#.

Code:

```
        SpotifyLocalAPIClass spotify = new SpotifyLocalAPIClass();

        if(spotify.Connect())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not connected");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: I can't verify this locally yet, as I'm in the progress of rebuilding my dev machine, but looking at your code, you seem to be skipping 2 prereqs. I'm looking at one of the examples in the repo and the first two checks made after instanciating `SpotifyLocalAPIClass` is `IsSpotifyRunning` and `IsSpotifyWebHelperRunning`.

Comment: @YannickMeeus you are right, that worked for me. The WebHelper was not running.